# Online (pdf) resources on doxastic logic

Tags: logic, belief

I would be interested in learning more about doxastic logic.

The [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic) is rather detailed but still obviously very summarised and references therein are either papers with a paywall or books with a prohibitive price from what I have seen.

Would there be lectures on the subject available online in pdf format?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best starting point is the Stanford site on 'Logic of Belief Revision' : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-belief-revision/.

§8.2 is on the precise topic of doxastic logic. There are also references to further reading.

Stanford offers in my view one of the best online philosophy sites on the web; Stanford's academic excellence shows in the material it puts online.